# How to show transfer progress during a DataSnap transmission?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I have a ISAPI DataSnap server and a client application, which communicate over the web. I have been looking for a way to show data transmission progress when the client application is retrieving data or applying updates, but so far I haven't found anything except to set `ClientDataSet.PacketRecord` to a small number and run a loop to retrieve packets. Since my data contains BLOB data, this method isn't very practical, as each record might grow beyond 1024KB. Is there a way to monitor the actual TCP/IP communication between my client application and the server?

---

Is it possible to throw a `TIdHTTPProxyServer` on my client application and monitor data transmission using it?

Update:
Even if that's possible, I'm concerned about the send/receive routine being executed in the main thread, and thus blocking any GUI activity. I read somewhere that I could execute these calls (`Refresh` and `ApplyUpdates`) in separate threads, but I haven't got a clue on how to do this.

Comment: I think so, but it will also trigger a firewall alert if the proxy server opens a local HTTP port

Comment: @mjn That's fine. I can handle Windows Firewall and other major firewalls during installation. Also, please take a look at the update